# Interoperability between System.Windows.Forms.Application and System.Windows.Application

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I have to integrate a WPF UI into a .NET 2.0 application.

ObservableCollection needs to be modified in the GUI Dispatcher thread, so I came up with a solution involving `InvokeLater()`

```
ObservableCollection<Item> items;
public delegate void AddItemDelegate(Item i);

public void AddItem(Item item)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        new AddItemsDelegate(i => items.Add(i), item);
}
```

However, since the project was originally written with .NET 2.0, the main thread uses a `System.Windows.Forms.Application`, so `System.Windows.Application.Current` is null.

I can't just replace the current `System.Windows.Forms.Application` with a `System.Windows.Application` since my application heavily relies on this API and the two classes are widely incompatibles.

Is there a way to get the current `System.Windows.Application` ? Or a way to call `BeginInvoke()` on my `System.Windows.Forms.Application` ? Or am I deemed to write my own DIY system to delegate edition of the collection from the correct thread ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should save a reference to `SynchronizationContext.Current` from the UI thread (perhaps in a static property) and use it instead of the `Dispatcher`.

In WPF, this will return a [`DispatcherSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext.aspx); in WinForms, it will return a [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx).

You can then call [`Post`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) on the saved `SynchronizationContext`, which is equivalent to `BeginInvoke`.